# Resize an image retrieved from Google Drive using API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am using the following Python code to get a file from Google Drive:

```
theGoogleDriveFile = service.files().get(fileId=<googleDriveFileId>).execute()
```

How would I go about resizing this file if it is an image? I have tried the following:

```
resizedImage = images.resize(theGoogleDriveFile['downloadUrl'], 32, 32)
```

But I get the following error:

```
raise NotImageError()
NotImageError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
theGoogleDriveFile = service.files().get(fileId=<googleDriveFileId>).execute()
result = urlfetch.fetch(theGoogleDriveFile['webContentLink'])                
resizedImage = images.resize(result.content, 32, 32)
```